# Can't access python glass server from virtualbox on localhost

Tags: python, server-administration

I have Virtualbox container with FreeBSD installed where Aquarium with Glass server are running on port 9080, it is accessible from within the container. Container network is configured to use NAT+DHCP. I forwarded guest's port 9080 to use localhost's 39080. On localhost when i do `curl localhost:39080` --> `Empty reply from server` . However when I start e.g `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9080` on the guest I can access it on localhost. Looks like server configuration issue, have anybody experienced similar issue? Your mana will increase for any help. Thank's.

Comment: Sorry. You already noticed in your tag that this is an administration, NOT a programming question. You might want to migrate this to SuperUser, where it is on- and not off-topic like it is on StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok, thank you, will do so.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: in server settings I need to replace `127.0.0.1` with `0.0.0.0`, so the server will be accessible from outside.